# Problema al rotar un array

Tags: javascript

Tengo problemas con mi programa.. Creo que es de codificación.. es la primera vez que toco javascript y voy algo perdida..

Básicamente lo que tengo que conseguir es que mi array de colores se mueva.. es decir el color gris pase al último.. una rotación a la izquierda... Tiene que haber algo mal pero no sé verlo..

Y luego necesito otra cosa más que en eso ya voy más perdida aún.. Tengo que conseguir que  Primer color:  me diga el color que hay actualmente en primera posición..

```js
var llistaColors = ["grey", "black", "blue", "yellow", "red", "purple", "green", "white", "orange", "pink"];
var llistaNomColors = ["Gris", "negre", "blau", "Groc", "Vermell", "lila", "Verd", "blanc", "Taronja", "rosa"];
var llistaRotada = llistaColors;

function iniColors() {
  for (i = 0; i < llistaColors.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("color" + i).style.backgroundColor = llistaColors[i];
  }
  var primer = llistaRotada[0];

  function mouColorsEsquerra(llistaRotada) {
    for (x = 0; x < llistaRotada.length - 1; x++)
      llistaRotada[x] = llistaRotada[x + 1];
    llistaRotada[x] = primero;
    return llistaRotada

  }

  function pintaColors() {
    for (y = 0; y < llistaRotada.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("color" + i).style.backgroundColor = llistaRotada[y];
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.contenedorColors {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.colordiv {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.info {
  clear: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.info button {
  background-color: white;
  /* Green */
  border: 2px solid #555555;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.info p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#colorDetall {
  display: none;
  width: 600px;
  height: 340px;
}

.repte {
  float: left;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.colorRepte {
  clear: left;
  margin-left: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.repte p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}


/*estils finestra repteResultats */

#contenedor {
  text-align: center;
}

.lletraGran {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px gray;
}

.missatge {
  display: none;
}

.estadistiques-taula {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Mou Colors</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="colors.css">
  <script src="js/colors1.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="iniColors()">
  <h1>Mou colors</h1>
  <div id="contenedorColors" class="contenedorColors">
    <div id="color0" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color1" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color2" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color3" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color4" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color5" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color6" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color7" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color8" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color9" class="colordiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="info" class="info">
    <p>
      <button id="brotar1" type="button" onclick="mouColorsEsquerra()">rotar 1</button>
    </p>
    <p>Primer color: <span id="primerColor"><span>
   </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo simplemente usando los métodos [`Array#unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/unshift) y [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/pop).

> El método `unshift` agrega uno o más elementos al inicio de un array, mientras que `pop` elimina el último de un array y lo devuelve.

En cada iteración, sucederá lo siguiente:

- Se elimina el último elemento de `colors` y se devuelve.
- Se agrega éste elemento **al inicio** del array.

De esta manera da la impresión de "estar rotando".

**Ejemplo**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var colors = ["grey", "black", "blue", "yellow", "red", "purple", "green", "white", "orange", "pink"];
  var names = ["Gris", "negre", "blau", "Groc", "Vermell", "lila", "Verd", "blanc", "Taronja", "rosa"];

  var btnRotate = document.getElementById('brotar1');
  var colorDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.colordiv');
  var currentColor = document.getElementById('primerColor');
  
  btnRotate.addEventListener('click', rotate);

  // inicializamos la paleta y el primer color
  palette();
  updateColorName(names[0]);

  function palette() {
    for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      paint(i, colors[i]);
    }
  }

  function rotate() {
    colors.unshift(colors.pop());
    names.unshift(names.pop());

    updateColorName(names[0]);
    palette();
    this.disabled = true;

    window.setInterval(function() {
      colors.unshift(colors.pop());
      names.unshift(names.pop());

      updateColorName(names[0]);
      palette();
    }, 1000);
  }

  function paint(i, color) {
    colorDivs[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
  }

  function updateColorName(name) {
    currentColor.textContent = name;
  }
});
```

```css
.contenedorColors {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.colordiv {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.info {
  clear: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.info button {
  background-color: white;
  /* Green */
  border: 2px solid #555555;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.info p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#colorDetall {
  display: none;
  width: 600px;
  height: 340px;
}

.repte {
  float: left;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.colorRepte {
  clear: left;
  margin-left: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.repte p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}


/*estils finestra repteResultats */

#contenedor {
  text-align: center;
}

.lletraGran {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px gray;
}

.missatge {
  display: none;
}

.estadistiques-taula {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button:disabled {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-color: #ddd;
  color: #eee;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Mou Colors</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="colors.css">
  <script src="js/colors1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Mou colors</h1>
  <div id="contenedorColors" class="contenedorColors">
    <div id="color0" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color1" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color2" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color3" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color4" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color5" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color6" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color7" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color8" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color9" class="colordiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="info" class="info">
    <p>
      <button id="brotar1" type="button">rotar 1</button>
    </p>
    <p>Primer color: <span id="primerColor"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: He mirado tu código y adaptado al mio ya que los métodos tienen que llamarse de X forma y me da error la última linea... me dice esto:  SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'textContent' of undefined or null reference 

No tengo ni idea de por que..

Comment: Sucede porque el código se está ejecutando cuando aún no ha cargado el DOM. Es importante que, cuando trabajes manipulando el DOM como en este caso para cambiar el nombre, pongas el código dentro de `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { // tu codigo });`. De esta manera tu código se ejecutará cuando el DOM ya ha sido cargado.

Comment: y eso tengo que ponerlo en cada función=? :S

Comment: No, **todo el código** que tengas va dentro de eso. Se ejecuta una sola vez.

Comment: Ahora el error que tengo es que no me lee el resto de funciones. Voy un poco perdida con el tema como podrás comprobar.. xDsorry

Comment: Por más que miro no consigo hacerlo.. T_T

Comment: @MontseMdk he actualizado mi respuesta poniéndote el código para que solo le modifiques los nombres. Analiza el código y estúdialo. Cualquier duda, puedes publicarla.

Comment: Ahora te comento! ;)

Comment: Ahora si!!! Perfecto!!! Lo único que tengo otro problema.. XD Que no para de rotar... he estado mirando y veo sino entiendo mal que el 1000 es la velocidad no? Si solo quiero que lo haga 1 vez por cada vez que aprieto? 

Lo siento!!

Comment: Jaja, no te preocupes. Lo he hecho así para que veas el comportamiento. Solo elimina esta parte de la función `rotate`: `this.disabled = true;

    window.setInterval(function() {
      colors.unshift(colors.pop());
      names.unshift(names.pop());

      updateColorName(names[0]);
      palette();
    }, 1000);`

Comment: Gustavo sigo teniendo un problema.. XD Es decir por el explorador el programa me funciona perfectamente pero cada vez que le doy al botón me sale un error... como el siguiente: SCRIPT5009: 'mouColorsEsquerra' is undefined 

se ejecuta pero eso es lógico? xD

Comment: No, no es lógico. Mira su los nombres coinciden. Cuando veas errores de tipo `is undefined` quiere decir que el atributo o función que has llamado **no está definida o no existe**. Puede pasar que olvides una letra del nombre de la función.

Comment: miraré a ver que puede pasar.. el tema es que el programa se ejecuta y mueve el cuadro.. pero sale todo el rato ese error.. xD la que estoy liando.. Voy a cenar y luego despejada seguro que sale!

Gracias!! :**********

Comment: Sigo con el mismo problema... xD lo subiré en un. Nuevo debate.. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Te pongo otra propuesta; en este caso se utiliza el método `Array.shift()` (a diferencia de `unshift()` usado por **Gustavo García**): de esta manera la rotación será de derecha a izquierda. Otra diferencia es que se utiliza un solo array para contener tanto los colores como sus nombres (colección de objetos con ambas propiedades): de esta manera no se tiene que estar sincronizando dos arreglos (arrays) por separado.

A ver qué te parece. Saludos.

```js
var llistaColors = [
  { color: 'grey', nombre: 'Gris' },
  { color: 'black', nombre: 'negre' },
  { color: 'blue', nombre: 'blau' },
  { color: 'yellow', nombre: 'Groc' },
  { color: 'red', nombre: 'Vermell' },
  { color: 'purple', nombre: 'lila' },
  { color: 'green', nombre: 'Verd' },
  { color: 'white', nombre: 'blanc' },
  { color: 'orange', nombre: 'Taronja' },
  { color: 'pink', nombre: 'rosa' }
];

function iniColors() {
  pintaColors(llistaColors);
}

function pintaColors(arr){
  for(y = 0; y < arr.length; y++){
    document.getElementById("color"+y).style.backgroundColor = arr[y].color;
  }
  document.getElementById("primerColor").innerHTML = arr[0].nombre;
}

function rotar(arr) {
  var llistaRotada = llistaColors;
  var prim = llistaRotada.shift();
  llistaRotada.push(prim);
  pintaColors(llistaRotada);
}
```

```css
.contenedorColors {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.colordiv {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.info {
  clear: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.info button {
  background-color: white;
  /* Green */
  border: 2px solid #555555;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.info p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#colorDetall {
  display: none;
  width: 600px;
  height: 340px;
}

.repte {
  float: left;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.colorRepte {
  clear: left;
  margin-left: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.repte p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}


/*estils finestra repteResultats */

#contenedor {
  text-align: center;
}

.lletraGran {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px gray;
}

.missatge {
  display: none;
}

.estadistiques-taula {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Mou Colors</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="colors.css">
  <script src="js/colors1.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="iniColors()">
  <h1>Mou colors</h1>
  <div id="contenedorColors" class="contenedorColors">
    <div id="color0" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color1" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color2" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color3" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color4" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color5" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color6" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color7" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color8" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color9" class="colordiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="info" class="info">
    <p>
      <button id="brotar1" type="button" onclick="rotar()">rotar 1</button>
    </p>
    <p>Primer color: <span id="primerColor"><span>
   </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: mil gracias!! El problema es que no puedo tocar los arrays de como estan! xD

Comment: Entonces revisa la respuesta de Gustavo arriba: él no cambió tus arrays (sólo los nombres). Si necesitas rotar en el modo que yo definí (derecha a izquierda) revisa el código que pongo, usando shift en vez de unshift y utilizando una variable intermedia para apoyo del "salto".

Comment: muchas gracias me viene bien aprender varias formas! :)